# Android application update only for one country

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services

Guys I have already submitted my application on Google Play store only for 4 countries.

But Somehow the second version of the app should be available only for 1 country.

If in Google Play Price & Distribution part I only enable for that country is the rest of 3 country will get updates or not?

I need confirmation before releasing update on Play Store

Comment: Cannot find this information on the net, perhaps you should contact google support

Comment: @TimCastelijns I couldn't find about this as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Google Play not allow to update app only for one country. It means its not possible.***

---

> as per @Tim Castelijns's comment ***But what happens if you update the
>   allowed countries from 4 countries to 1, and then update the app?***
>
> if your app(like v 1.0.0) live in 4 country then you disable 3 country
>   at that time your app not showing in Google play for that 3
>   country(you current user able to use your app but you cannot get new
>   user. also if your app have In-App purchase then it may not work).
>
> rest of one country: current user get updates as well new user able to
>   install app from Google play.
>
> whenever, you again enable that 3 country: all user of that 3 country
>   are get updates(new user get newer version of app). so, it meaning less.

---

### simples way is: upload new version of App for all Country

Comment: Thank you @Dhawai for your complete answer you helped a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Google Play does not support this which you are looking.

It is not possible to provide an update to only a specific region.

Comment: It's mean the users that have application installed on their device will get updates but new users can't install the app?

Comment: But what happens if you update the allowed countries from 4 countries to 1, and then update the app?