# Deploy an Android app upgrade to selected country

Tags: android, apk

I have an existing app available to all countries in google play. Now I have added new features to the app and I want to release these features to a specific country for testing and feedback before releasing them to all countries. Is this possible in google play?

There is an option in google play where you can select the countries you want your app to be distributed. My question is if I exclude some countries, will my app (including both the existing version and the new version) disappear in these countries? Can I exclude certain countries only for the new version and still keep my old version available to these countries?

Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android application update only for one country](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37207269/android-application-update-only-for-one-country)

Comment: yes, that answered my questions.

Comment: @jiawen flag your question as a duplicate then, so a moderator can close/mark as duplicate